# Mysql passing variable

Tags: mysql

Here is our current query:

```
SELECT info.yearID, info.nameFirst, info.nameLast, info.HR
FROM (
SELECT a.yearID, a.nameFirst, a.nameLast, a.HR FROM (
SELECT @curRank := @curRank+1 as rank, i.nameFirst, i.nameLast, i.masterID, i.HR, i.yearID 
FROM (  SELECT (select @curRank := 0), m.nameFirst, b.yearID, m.nameLast, b.masterId, sum(b.HR) as HR
FROM master as m left join batting as b on b.masterID = m.masterID
WHERE b.yearID = 1882 group by b.masterID) 
as i ORDER BY i.HR desc
)a 
WHERE a.HR = (SELECT i.HR
FROM ( 
SELECT (select @curRank := 0), m.nameFirst, b.yearID, m.nameLast, b.masterId, sum(b.HR) as HR
FROM master as m left join batting as b on b.masterID = m.masterID
WHERE b.yearID = 1882 
group by b.masterID
) 
as i  ORDER BY i.HR desc limit 1)) as info ;
```

We need to make it so that the 1882 is not hardcoded, but goes from 1871 - 2013.

I am not looking for the answer, just a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b.yearID = @yearVar
```

^^ That @ symbol will be parsed and how you're treating @curRank will be similar. It's a means of supplying some type of dynamic value.

Comment: If I was to make it so @yearVar could be a value from another query, how would you do that?

Comment: Aren't you passing in @curRank from some external means? Use a loop to go through a set of years you wish to use.

Answer (score 0):

just change it to:

```
WHERE b.yearID BETWEEN 1871 AND 2013
```